# Prevent user enter same username and email to the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I done using email authentication register new user to the database but now I met the problem of validate username and email which is prevent user enter the same username and password to the database so can you guys help me see whether the retrieve data statement got error?

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = user.getUid();//getuser id


    run = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Run);
    rpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpw);
    rage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rage);

    //rbm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmale);
    //rbfm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbfemale);

    re = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Re);
    rpn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpn);
    ra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ra);
    rpc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpc);

    //rbstd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbstd);
    //rbtt= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtt);

    final Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Rbt);

    br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            usnm = run.getText().toString().trim();
            pswd = rpw.getText().toString().trim();
            email = re.getText().toString().trim();

            ref.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Object a = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(usnm)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (usnm.length()<8){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot less then 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (usnm.length()>8){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot greater then 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (ref.child(uid).child("username").equals(usnm)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username had been taken already! Please try another one.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pswd)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (pswd.length()<8){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot less then 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (pswd.length()>8){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot greater then 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Email cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (ref.child(uid).child("email").equals(email)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Email had been taken already! Please try another one.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

            register(usnm, pswd, email);

        }//end of onclick
    });
```

I hope can prevent user enter same input during registration.
[image]

Comment: do you want that use already exit like?

Comment: why not check it database procedure or web sevice

Comment: yah...using when button click to check whether the database got same usermail and email. But it's not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, i recomand you implementing [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) which is the best solution in your case. This approach solves all you problems regaring authentication and saves time because you don't need to maintain any code.

If you still want to use your approach, to check for uniqueness i recomand you change your database structure a little bit. In stead of using a `unique key` or the `UID`, i recomand you using the `email address`. It's also unique and very easy to use. Remember, using the UID is not always the best solution because if you let the user the possibility to delete his account, if he signs in again, another UID is generated and this will cause you troubles.

To check an email address / user-name also for uniqueness, i recomand you creating another nodes in your Firebase database (emailAddresses / userNames) in which you need to add all email addresses and all user-names. To verify the existents of a email address/user-name, just add a listener on that particular node and use the `exists()` method on the `dataSnapshop` object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The solution that  found out is 
 ref.child(uid).orderByChild("username").equalTo(validateName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
But still thanks to your suggestion

Comment: you was right about it now the uid really make me headache

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to take the uid after you have registered successfully a user on your Firebase. You need to add an `onCompleteListener` on your registration and after Firebase returns the uid you can query Firebase to get username and email.

```
public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    //Problem with saving the data
    if (databaseError != null) {

    } else {
        //User has registered, retrieve his uid
        String uniqueKey = databaseReference.getKey();        
    }
}
```

Comment: But now currently I just want to validate the username and email only whether the database also got the same input and I use uid as the child like the picture that I show. I just want to retrieve the username and email from the uid so do you have the solution for my question?

Comment: Now I'm doing registration as you can see from the above code. My question is do you have solution to get the username and email under uid to prevent user type in the same input to the database so do you get it?

Comment: Very appreciate you and your solution.

Comment: No problem mate can you put the answer as accepted and vote up. Thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the uniqueness problem. Using the UID is not always the best approach.